# Clear the extensions loaded from server and again load it after regular interval of setTimeout in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i am in trouble because of this problem.

i want to load the extensions from server and then, clear it after few milliseconds and reload those extensions.i want to repeat this step again and again in my java-script to update the status of extension whether it is busy (display red light) or free(green light) like chat-box.

I have tried through Ajax but its not working it only load the extensions once with its state (busy or free) but cannot toggle the state when call got disconnected.if i refresh the page again then it toggle its state from green to red or vice verse.

Please help

THANK YOU :)

Comment: What causes you to get disconnected?